# Single Regular Expression to match ranges (1999-2010) or just a single value (2010)?

Tags: javascript, regex

In general, I don't think I've come across a generic solution to this problem. How do you match a string that can be a range, or just a single value?

Say I want to match [complex] dates:

- 1999 - 2010
- 323 BCE - 100 CE
- 323 BC
- 1995-99
- 323 - 322 BC

What is the general regular expression "template" that can parse both of these cases:

1. The start/end date if it exists
2. Otherwise, just a single date

To match "1999 - 2010", you can just do

```
/(\d+\s*)-(\s*\d+)/ // where $1 and $2 are start and end
```

To match the more complex "323 BCE - 100 CE", you can do

```
/(\w+\s*\w+)\s*-\s*(\w+\s*\w+)/
```

And to match the simpler "323 BC", you can do

```
/\w+\s*\w+/
```

But how do you write one expression that first checks for the *range* (323 BCE - 100 CE), and if that doesn't exist, checks for a single value (323 BC), that can also handle the other examples in the list above?

Answer (score 2):

By making the latter part of the match optional.

```
/(\w+\s*\w+)(?:\s*-\s*(\w+\s*\w+))?/
```

**Examples** (JavaScript)

```
"1900 - 2000".match(/(\w+\s*\w+)(?:\s*-\s*(\w+\s*\w+))?/);
//["1900 - 2000", "1900", "2000"]

"1900 BC".match(/(\w+\s*\w+)(?:\s*-\s*(\w+\s*\w+))?/);
//["1900 BC", "1900 BC", undefined]
```

Note the outer, optional part is made to be non-matching, so the array of results contains only the sub-matches you're interested in.

It would also be an idea to tighten the pattern efficiency-wise e.g. look for numbers rather than anything alphanumeric, and allow only single spaces (if this was acceptable) rather than zero or more.

Answer (score 0):

Just to throw in another pattern that might work the way you want it;

`((\d+)( [A-Za-z]+|))((-| - )\d+( [A-Za-z]+|)|)`

And as with Utkanos' pattern, this might need some tightening to *not* match anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for something like this:

```
var pattern = /(\d+)(\s*(\w+))?(\s*-\s*(\d+)(\s*(\w+))?)?/;
var strings = [
    '1999 - 2010',
    '323 BCE - 100 CE',
    '323 BC',
    '1995-99',
    '323 - 322 BC'
];

for (var i=0, s; s = strings[i]; i++) {
    var m  = s.match(pattern);
    console.log(
        m[1], // beginning year
        m[3], // beginning b/c/e
        m[5], // end year
        m[7]  // end b/c/e
    );
}
```

which outputs

```
1999  undefined  2010       undefined
323   BCE        100        CE
323   BC         undefined  undefined
1995  undefined  99         undefined
323   undefined  322        BC
```

---

The trick here is to understand that `(group)?` makes `(group)` optional. Analogous to this, `(foo)+` and `(foo){3}` can be used to make the group match at least once or exactly three times.

Groups `(foo)` are, by default, capturing groups. That means their result will be contained in the array returned by String#match(). You can mark groups to be non-capture like so: `(?:wont-be-captured)`. With this, we can modify above pattern even further:

```
var pattern = /(\d+)(?:\s*(\w+))?(?:\s*-\s*(\d+)(?:\s*(\w+))?)?/;
for (var i=0, s; s = strings[i]; i++) {
    var m  = s.match(pattern);
    console.log(m[1], m[2], m[3], m[4]);
}
```